# Removing \n from a list

Tags: python-3.x

so i'm currently learning about mail merging and was issued a challenge on it. The idea is to open a names file, read the name on the current line and then replace it in the letter and save that letter as a new item.

I figured a good idea to do this would be a for loop.

Open file > for loop > append names to list > loop the list and replace ect.

Except when I try to actually append the names to the list, i get this:

```
['Aang\nZuko\nAppa\nKatara\nSokka\nMomo\nUncle Iroh\nToph']
```

The code I am using is:

```
invited_names = []

with open ("./Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as names:
    invited_names.append(names.read())
    for item in invited_names:
        new_names = [str.strip("\n") for str in invited_names]

        print(new_names)
```

Have tried to replace the \n and now .strip but I have not been able to remove the \n. Any ideas?

EDIT: not sure if it helps but the .txt file for the names looks like this:

```
Aang
Zuko
Appa
Katara
Sokka
Momo
Uncle Iroh
Toph
```

Comment: try `invited_names.extend(names.read_lines())` - `read()` returns the full content of a text file as one string. `read_lines()` returns a list of strings representing all lines in that file.

Comment: Look up the string split function: 'Aang\nZuko\nAppa\nKatara\nSokka\nMomo\nUncle Iroh\nToph'.split('\n') gives you a list of names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, **read()** only returns a giant string of what you have in your invited_names.txt file. But instead, you can use **readlines()** which returns a list which contains strings of every line (Thanks to  codeflush.dev for the comment). Then use **extend()** method to add this list to another list **invited_names**.

Again, you are using **for loop** and **list comprehension** at the same time. As a result, you are running the same list comprehension code for many times. So, you can cut off any of them. But I prefer you should keep the list comprehension because it is efficient.

Try this code:

```
invited_names = []

with open ("./Input/Names/invited_names.txt") as names:
    invited_names.extend(names.readlines())             # <--
    new_names = [str.strip("\n") for str in invited_names]
    print(new_names)
```